# Pandas: Conditionally fill column using a function based on other columns values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing, mask

I have a Pandas DataFrame that contains two sets of coordinates (lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2). I have a function that computes distance using these coordinates. But some of the rows in the dataframe are invalid. I would like to apply my function only to valid rows and save the result of the function to a 'dist' column (the column already exists in the dataframe). I want something like this SQL:

```
UPDATE dataframe
SET dist=calculate_dist(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
WHERE lat1 IS NOT NULL AND lat2 IS NOT NULL AND user_id>100;
```

How can I achieve this?

I tried using `df = df.apply(calculate_dist, axis=1)` but with this approach I need to process all rows, not only the rows that match my conditions, and I need to have an if statement inside the calculate_dist function that ignores invalid rows. Is there a better way?

I know that similar questions already appeared on StackOverflow but I could not find any question that utilizes both a function and conditional selection of rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) first:

```
mask = (df.lat1.notnull()) & (df.lat2.notnull()) & (df.user_id>100)

df['dist'] = df[mask].apply(calculate_dist, axis=1)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lat1':[1,2,np.nan,1],
                   'lon1':[4,5,6,2],
                   'lat2':[7,np.nan,9,3],
                   'lon2':[1,3,5,1],
                   'user_id':[200,30,60,50]})

print (df)
   lat1  lat2  lon1  lon2  user_id
0   1.0   7.0     4     1      200
1   2.0   NaN     5     3       30
2   NaN   9.0     6     5       60
3   1.0   3.0     2     1       50

#function returning Series
def calculate_dist(x):
    return x.lat2 - x.lat1

mask = (df.lat1.notnull()) & (df.lat2.notnull()) & (df.user_id>100)
df['dist'] = df[mask].apply(calculate_dist, axis=1)
print (df)
   lat1  lat2  lon1  lon2  user_id  dist
0   1.0   7.0     4     1      200   6.0
1   2.0   NaN     5     3       30   NaN
2   NaN   9.0     6     5       60   NaN
3   1.0   3.0     2     1       50   NaN
```